# django models selecting users satisfying a criteria and taking intersection

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following two database model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()

class Channel(models.Model):
    subscribed = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, 
                                        related_name="subscribed")
```

Given, a channel I want to display the users subscribed to the channel in one column and the ones who are *not subscribed* to the channel in other column. 
Getting the users who are subscribed to a channel is no issues. How do I select the users who are not subscribed to the channel and the send the user profile objects of users who are not subscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `exclude` instead of `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = Channel.objects.get(pk=1)
subscribed = c.subscribed_set.all()
not_subscribed = UserProfile.objects.exclude(pk__in=[s.pk for s in subscribed])
```